# How can I get the type of calendar that is used in the application

Tags: c#, .net, localization, calendar

We have an application that runs on Windows, where users may change their regional settings (OS settings) and choose to work using the Persian, Japanese, or Thai calendars.

[image]

I am able to determine the `CultureInfo` and currently used `Calendar` using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar` (`System.Globalization`). But I am unsure how to determine if user is using Gregorian calendar or some other calendar.

Comment: here is something that may help you in regards to determining if the calendar is Gregorian calendar or not http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.optionalcalendars(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What type is the `Calendar`? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar(v=vs.110).aspx) states that [GregorianCalendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.gregoriancalendar(v=vs.110).aspx) inherits from Calendar (And it appears that there are multiple other types of calendar - see first link (msdn))

Answer (score -1):

You can test:

```
if (System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.ToString()   !="System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar")     
{
MessageBox.Show("Ivalid System Calender The Current Is "+ System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.ToString()+ Environment.NewLine + "Please Convert To GregorianCalendar");
return;
}
```